# Oracle exporting SQL of the Database structure

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to create an sql script that can recreate a DB that I already have. I want to recreate the DB without data inside.

So is there anyway with sqlplus of exporting a DB of a user?

Comment: You want only a DDL export? I.e. the DB schema without the data in it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two basic approaches.

The first is to export a dump file.  This can be with the Datapump utility:

```
$ expdp apc/pw directory=data_dump_dir dumpfile=apc_20100707.dmp content=METADATA_ONLY
```

[Find out more](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10825/dp_export.htm#i1006388).

Datapump was introduced in Oracle10g.  In earlier versions of the database we could use the EXP utility to do the same thing.

```
$ exp apc/pw dumpfile=apc_20100707.dmp rows=N
```

To import the file we use the matching `impdp` (or `imp`) utilities.

That is the OS approach.  To generate actual SQL scripts we can use the built-in DBMS_METADATA package, introduced in Oracle 9i.  This is a bit more work but offers much finer control over the details of the exported objects.  [Find out more](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10802/d_metada.htm#1019417).

Answer (score 12):

From [this blog post](http://www.dba-oracle.com/art_builder_get_schema_syntax.htm), it looks like there is a package called `dbms_metadata` that can generate `create table` SQL.  Example:

```
 set pagesize 0
 set long 90000
 set feedback off

 set echo off 
 spool filename.sql 
 connect username/password;
 SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE',u.table_name)
     FROM USER_TABLES u;
 SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('INDEX',u.index_name)
     FROM USER_INDEXES u;
 spool off;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use SQL Developer to create sql scripts, as described [here](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/sqldev/r30/SQLdev3.0_Import_Export/sqldev3.0_import_export.htm).