# Integration of Oracle and Subversion

Tags: java, database, svn, version-control, oracle11g

I am managing a web-based project based on java, subversion and svn with 8 developers. Unfortunately, mangling DB changes is a big problem for the project. In our case, every user may update the tables and forgot to put the change scripts in svn. So, it takes lots of our time to see and debug an issue raised because of an un-updated table or view.

So, I wonder, is there any method, tool or plug-in for oracle 11g to keep all DB changes as scripts for us somewhere, e.g. on svn?

**Edit 1:** Getting a dump from the whole db does not solve my problem, because in the real environment I cannot discard customer data and go back to a new dump.

Comment: _"In our case, every user may update the tables and forgot to put the change scripts in svn."_ That's your problem. You just need better change management procedures. People _have_ to commit changes it's the only way the system works. If people are not committing changes it's a problem with the management of the situation rather than the tools you are using.

Comment: @Ben - Like you, I do not believe that this is a problem of my tools. I have a problem and I think it may be solved by automatic generation of change scripts. Therefor, if you have any better solution, you may tell me. In addition, would you please propose a better change management procedure for our case??

Comment: I don't unfortunately, that's why I posted a comment rather then an answer. I'm as reliant on you on other people and their committing their changes. The only difference is that people do commit their changes where I work and if they don't they normally get found out as the problems they cause are fairly obvious. My current problem,there'll always be a problem, is crap commit messages :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is just what you need. An open source database change management system. Liquibase. 
http://www.liquibase.org/

Answer (score 1):

Do not store change scripts, only scripts that drop and recreate all your objects.  Developers should change and run those scripts on a local instance, run automated unit tests, and then check-in their changes.

Rebuilding from scratch is *so* much better than constantly running alter scripts.  You'll never be in control of your application until everyone can easily rebuild the entire system from scratch.

(I assume you're asking about development on trunk, where you have lots of little changes.  For major upgrades, like moving from version 1.1 to version 1.2, you'll still need to use change scripts to help preserve data.)

Comment: I am talking exactly about moving a version from 1.1 to 1.2. How can i ensure that all of my change scripts are stored somewhere? Who can I guarantee that the stored change scripts can completely upgrade my DB to version 1.2?

Answer (score 0):

More cheap and worse solution, than Liquibase, according to [Oracle: exporting only schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049657/oracle-exporting-only-schema) topic, can be
post-commit hook, which

- `expdp ... DUMPFILE=file.dmp CONTENT=METADATA_ONLY` into dir, which is WC or special location in repository
- commit this file.dmp

Comment: But I do not need the dump file. I need the change scripts to migrate the DB form one version to another.

Comment: That is the thing we are doing right now. It is really frustrating. :--(

Answer (score 0):

There are two aspects to maintaining database changes. One, as you mentioned, in in the form of scripts that can be applied to an older schema to upgrade it. However, this is part of the answer, as it is really hard for a developer to look at scripts, parse them, and figure out how recent schema changes may affect their work.

So, in addition to change scripts, I would suggest that you also check in a human-readable version of the database metadata, in a text file. [SchemaCrawler](http://schemacrawler.sourceforge.net/) is one such free tool that is designed for this purpose, and produces rich metadata information in a format that is designed to be diffed. I have found that database metadata changes over time become traceable if you make it a nightly process to automate check-ins of schema metadata.

Comment: MerC Agha Sualeh !!! I just wonder how your tool can detect a column rename? Is is really a rename of the column should be dropped and inserted again???

Comment: Column renames pose problem, and need to be managed with a change management tool. http://www.liquibase.org/manual/rename_column